# go ldflags set variable value not working

Tags: go

I'm trying to use go build to update a variable inside my project:

full project path:

```
c:\goprojects\src\deployment\cl\apps\appName
```

run from c:\goprojects\src

```
 go install -ldflags="-X main.GitRev=adaf66c" deployment\cl\apps\appName\...
```

In the go project I have:

```
package main
var GitRev = "oldvalue"


func main() {
    fmt.Println("variable contents: ", GitRev)
}
```

Then from the command line I run:

```
..\bin\appName.exe
```

I'm expecting to see the value:

```
adaf66c
```

What I get:  variable contents:

```
oldvalue
```

Comment: Are you sure you are running the binary you just built?

Comment: yes, I can change the value of GitRev from 'oldvalue' to 'oldvalue1' and see that it changes the next time I build the appName.exe binary

Comment: I took your code, and: 1) `➜ go build -ldflags="-X main.GitRev=adaf66c"` 2) `➜ ./so-53402640 
variable contents:  adaf66c
` (it's linux though)

Comment: ya it should work. maybe related to the paths.  I also have a large project with many imports too, but shouldn't matter.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are just declaring a variable and not a flag. Import the flag package and assign it like so.

```
import "flag"
var GitRev = flag.String("GitRev", "oldvalue", "what it represents")
```

Comment: I'm sure you misunderstand the question